# I cannot print the value of fields

Tags: angular

I have written following code.

```
(await this.httpService.getVehicleDetail(CID)).subscribe(res=>{
  console.log(res);
});
```

The output in  the console.

```
{vehicleDetails: {…}}

vehicleDetails:

vehicleDetail: Array(1)

0: {ownerName: null, vehicleRegistrationDetailsId: null, vehicleNumber: null, vehicleTypeName: null, 
chassisNumber: null, …}
length: 1
```

I couldn't able to print the value of field name ownerName.Please help me.

Comment: It seems like your api returns an array with one element where `ownerName` is null. I suppose there is a problem with the API, how you use the API, or the data that the server contains.

Comment: You are using `await` and `subscribe` for the same api call, this is not correct. What are you expecting from this api response, a Promise or an Observable?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `console.log(res.vehicleDetail[0].ownerName)`